# Converting JS to TS - React Hooks

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

I'm making a basic chat app with React w/Typescript. I understand that TS requires type declaration.

I would like to convert this from JS to TS, what all would need to be changed and where do I declare the type in each case?

**CODE**

```
function App() {

 const [rooms, setRooms]   = useState(''); // type str
 const [roomId, setRoomId] = useState(''); // type str
 const [user, setUser]     = useState(''); // type str

function updateRoom(id) {

 return id === '' ? setRoomId('') : setRoomId(id) // ??

}

return (
 <div className="app">
   <div className="room">
   {rooms.map((room, index) => (
     <Room key={index} index={index} room={room} />
   ))}
 </div>
</div>
)
}
```

**TS**

```
function App() {

   const [rooms, setRooms] type Str = useState(''); 

}
```

Would it be something like this?

Comment: not sure I understand what you are asking

Comment: @Federkun question edited

Comment: I mean, you can leverage typescript type inference, and do nothing. `user`, `roomId`, etc. are already typed as string. You could always do `const foo = useState<string>(...)`, but in this case seems unnecessary

Comment: Just change the file extension to `.tsx` and then you fix the type errors that pop up. if you are having trouble with anything specific once you've done that, then that is what I we could be more help with.

Comment: would just `.ts` work? because i started a create react app with a typescript flag

Comment: _Would it be something like this?_ No. We won't teach you typescript here any better than [the official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html) could do. Also, i highly recommend jsut playing with some typescript froms scratch before converting any existing react code. That will be a steeper learning curve.

Comment: gotcha, i've looked at that, i guess im just looking for someone to help me with that one example and then i think i can get it. the destructuring part is throwing me off, the syntax and where to declare the type is where im not sure what to do

Comment: what's wrong with the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript only requires typing where it can't be inferred.

```
const [rooms, setRooms] = useState('');
```

Because of how `useState` is typed, typescript knows that when passed a string, it will return something like this type:

```
[string, (newRooms: string) => void]
```

Which gets destructured into your value and your setter.

So typescript will know that `rooms` will be a string because you pass a string to `useState`.

This code should work as is in typescript. Just convert it and fix what errors come up.

---

But in case it can't be inferred, you can give it a hint:

```
const [foo, setFoo] = useState(null as string | null)
```

Now `foo` could be `null` or `string`, but `null` is the default value on component mount.

Comment: you can `useState<null | string>(null)`